# What happens to closed questions

Tags: discussion

There is this recent quite broad question on decay in space. It has a suspected duplicate question that has been closed. Is closure of a new question, on the basis of another closed question a good thing? I actually think the old question received nice answers and should be reopened.

Moreover, when the other question is deleted, the present one will be put on hold and closed as a duplicate of a deleted question?

Comment: I believe I voted to close the first question because it showed no effort. However, when I read the second question in the reopen queue, I vote to reopen since it was a substantial improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I voted to reopen the old original question.

Comment: I would do so too but I'm on mobile for a while. Thanks for the support :)

Comment: @ChrisStronks For you interest: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245753/vote-to-reopen-in-the-ios-app Doesn't seem very popular though.